# AWS iOS SDK: Is it possible long poll or be notified when changes are made to a DynamoDB table?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am working on an app that requires near realtime updates for a certain table. Is there built in functionality with the current AWS iOS SDK to be notified when changes are made to a DynamoDB table. I've done a little reading and know about the [DynamoDB Streams](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html), but I didn't see anything about them when looking through the iOS API reference.

If the functionality doesn't exist in the iOS SDK yet, would it be possible to get the Dynamo shard information into my app from another source (i.e. REST API call)?

Comment: You are right the AWS SDK for iOS does not support dynamodb streams. Can you clarify if you need to be notified on the client or is it ok to do so on backend?

Comment: Ideally, I would like to be notified in the client side, but I could probably make due with only being notified on the backend.